Multiple Lines After Big Curly Bracket in Align* Environment
Essentially I would like to reproduce this output:

but with proper syntax.  I am currently getting "Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;" as an error related to red marked area, as I understand now that I don't need inline math and align* environment.  When using only align* and changing code chunks around I wasn't able to reproduce my output, however.  Any help would be appreciated.
Original Code:
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}
    \item Set the initial conditions $T_0 = 0, \lambda_{{T_0}^+} = \lambda_0 \geq a$, $N_0 = 0$ and $k \in \{0, 1, 2, ..., K-1 \}$.
    \item Simulate the $(k+1)^{th}$ interarrival-time $S_{k+1}$ by

\[
S_{k+1} = \Biggl \{ 
\begin{align*}
& S_{k+1}^{(1)} \wedge  S_{k+1}^{(2)}, \quad  & D_{k+1} > 0\\
& S_{k+1}^{(2)}, \quad  & D_{k+1} < 0\\
\end{align*} 
\]

where 
\[
 D_{k+1} = 1 + \frac{\delta  \text{ln}U_1}{\lambda_{{T_k}^+} - a}, \quad  U_1 \sim  \text{U}[0,1],
\]

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

Thanks in advance!

Off-topic: Instead of \text{ln}, please write \ln. This will give you much better spacing both before and after "ln".

You cannot include an align inside an equation. Instead, use aligned:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  Set the initial conditions $T_0 = 0, \lambda_{T_0^+} = \lambda_0 \geq a$, $N_0 = 0$ and 
  $k \in \{0, 1, \dots, K - 1 \}$.
  
  \item
  Simulate the $(k + 1)^{\text{st}}$ interarrival-time $S_{k + 1}$ by
  \[
    S_{k+1} = \Biggl\{
    \begin{aligned}
      & S_{k + 1}^{(1)} \wedge S_{k + 1}^{(2)}, \quad  & D_{k + 1} > 0 \\
      & S_{k + 1}^{(2)},                        \quad  & D_{k + 1} < 0
    \end{aligned}
    \Biggr\}
  \]
  where 
  \[
    D_{k+1} = 1 + \frac{\delta \ln U_1}{\lambda_{T_k^+} - a}, \quad  U_1 \sim \text{U}[0, 1],
  \]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


For the sake of variety, here's a cases-based solution.

In the final row, observe the use of (i) an inline-style fraction instead of \frac and (ii) \mathcal{U} to denote the uniform distribution; this is akin to using \mathcal{N} to denote the normal distribution.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for `cases` environment
\newcommand\Tplus[1]{{T_{#1}}^{\mkern-6mu+}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Set the initial conditions $T_0 = 0$, 
$\lambda_{\Tplus{0}} = \lambda_0 \geq a$, 
$N_0 = 0$, and $k \in \{0, 1, 2,\allowbreak\dots, K-1 \}$.

\item Simulate the $(k+1)$\textsuperscript{st} inter-arrival time $S_{k+1}$ by
\[
S_{k+1} = 
\begin{cases} 
S_{k+1}^{(1)} \wedge S_{k+1}^{(2)} & \text{if $D_{k+1} > 0$,}\\[\jot]
S_{k+1}^{(2)} & \text{if $D_{k+1} < 0$,}
\end{cases}
\]
where 
\[
D_{k+1} = 1 + \delta \ln U_1/(\lambda_{\Tplus{k}} - a), 
\quad  U_1 \sim  \mathcal{U}[0,1]\,.
\]

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


The user wanted a right } as well.

@daleif - I wasn't sure if the OP really, really wanted it. :-)

Me neither.....

actually I didn't, was just trying to highlight the area that was going wrong.  Thank you both!
